# Unable to bind scroll event in tinymce

Tags: javascript

The solution below works quite well for a bunch of events, but when I am trying to bind `scroll`, it is not working. If I bind `scroll` event like this and scroll the browser's window (not editors) then it gets fired, but if I scroll inside editor it doesn't:

```
setup: function(ed){
    ed.on('scroll', function() {        
      console.log('Editor window scrolled!');       
    });
}
```

[binding event in tinymce](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/snfaab)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try the following:**

```
setup: function(ed){
    ed.on('init', function() { 
         $(ed.getWin()).bind('scroll', function(e){
            console.log('Editor window scrolled!');
        });
    });
```

**Its work for me :-)**